# ag-Grid Disable Multi Column Sorting on column cellRenderer click

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Can someone please assist me with this?

Initially the ag-Grid has the Name column set as the default sort and if one clicks on another column header, the sort changes properly.

After the page load, if one clicks on the link in column1 all is fine.

If instead after the page load one clicks on a column other than the Name column and then clicks on the link in column1, it appears that multi-column sorting is then happening since the column header of the Name column and the recently clicked column changes to include numbers to the right of the column header.

I would not like this behavior, is it possible?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wood-mcveb?file=/src/App.js

Setting the default sort seems to cause the issue. If I have no default sort specified all is fine yet I would like to set a default sort with the sort direction visible. Perhaps there is alternate way of specifying the default sort?

{ headerName: "Model", field: "model", sort: "desc" },

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to disable multi-sorting with `suppressMultiSort`. Set it to `true`, and it should give the behavior you expect.

The related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2913